# Trouble with Java 8 lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have an `interface` Operation a follows:

```
interface Operation {
    public double calc(double a, double b);
}
```

And I use it in an `enum`.

```
public enum Operations {

    POWER("^", new Operation(){
        public double calc(double a, double b) {
            return Math.pow(a, b);
        }
    }),
    MULTIPLICATION("*", new Operation(){
        public double calc(double a, double b) {
            return a * b;
        }
    }),
    //...

    private String op;
    private Operation calc;

    public Operations(String op, Operation calc) {
        this.op = op;
        this.calc = calc;
    }
}
```

I want to shorten my code using lambda expressions but I can't seem to get the syntax right. The oracle tutorials are a bit too complicated for me. Could some one explain it to me in a *simple* manner?

EDIT:
I've tried:

`POWER ("^", (double a, double b) -> Math.pow(a,b)),` and so on, but it doesn't compile.

---

**Fixed:**

```
import java.util.function.*;
public enum Operations {
    POWER("^", Math::pow),
    MULTIPLICATION("*", (double a,double b)->a*b),
    private final String op;
    private final DoubleBinaryOperator calc;
    Operations(String op, DoubleBinaryOperator calc) {
        this.op = op;
        this.calc = calc;
    }
    DoubleBinaryOperator getCalc() {
        return calc;
    }
}
```

Comment: what syntax did you tried so far?

Comment: Have you made sure you are 1) compiling with Java 8 and 2) compiling with source level 1.8?

Comment: @ambigram_maker It is rather surprising that your lambda doesn't work and mine work. In fact, both are equally valid syntax.

Comment: **Never ever have setters on an `enum`**. An `enum` should be immutable. All variables should be `final` and set in the constructor. Adding mutability to an `enum` is a major violation of coding best practice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Operation` being a functional interface, the expression:

```
new Operation(){
    public double calc(double a, double b) {
        return Math.pow(a, b);
    }
}
```

can be replaced with the following lambda expression:

```
(a, b) -> Math.pow(a, b)
```

or the method reference:

```
Math::pow
```

With this, your `enum` will become:

```
public enum Operations {

    POWER("^", Math::pow),
    MULTIPLICATION("*", (a, b) -> a * b);

    private String op;
    private Operation calc;

    public Operations(String op, Operation calc) {
        this.op = op;
        this.calc = calc;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I don't need that `Operation` interface?

Comment: @ambigram_maker You need that. That is what allows you to write that lamdbda expression.

Comment: Yes, you do need the `Operation` interface, but you do not need to create an anonymous inner class that implements the interface.

Comment: It should even be replaceable by `Math::pow`, no need for an actual lambda when a method reference suffices.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ah! Of course. Verfy often I forget about method references :)

Comment: Either `(a,b) -> Math.pow(a,b)` or `Math::pow`, not a combination of those

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Oops. Fixed.

Comment: @ambigram_maker I didn't get you? this is the lambda syntax. You can learn more about them from the oracle tutorials.

Comment: @ambigram_maker Actually you can remove the `Operation` interface. There is already a `DoubleBinaryOperator`. See @Boris's answer.

Comment: Oh no! it's not compiling! :-(

Comment: @ambigram_maker Are you sure you are compiling it under JDK 8? Try it with `javac` command.

Comment: It doesn't need to import anything or does it?

Comment: @ambigram_maker No need to import anything. How are you compiling it? Eclipse, Netbeans or javac?

Comment: NetBeans IDE 8.0 Do I need to change something?

Comment: @ambigram_maker Just make sure the compiler level is set to 1.8. Nothing you need to change. Or try compiling it once with `javac` command from command line. I'm sure it will compile provided you've Java 8 set in your classpath.

Comment: @RohitJain I've added the NetBeans info in my question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50112/discussion-between-ambigram-maker-and-rohit-jain)

Answer (score 3):

Delete the `interface Operation` as this is just a [`DoubleBinaryOperator`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleBinaryOperator.html)

```
public enum Operations {

    POWER("^", Math::pow),
    MULTIPLICATION("*", (a, b) -> a * b);

    private String op;
    private DoubleBinaryOperator calc;

    Operations(String op, DoubleBinaryOperator calc) {
        this.op = op;
        this.calc = calc;
    }
}
```

You can use a [method reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) for `Math.pow` as this already follows the required signature.

Comment: Nice. Didn't notice that :)

Comment: Bit more _name-specific_ I mean... One can understand what it's for straight away, isn't it?

Comment: @ambigram_maker yes, using the [standard functional interfaces](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) has the advantage of everyone knowing what they are - people don't need to hunt down the `Operation` interface to find out what is required. Also you have one fewer class in your source code.

Comment: @ambigram_maker There is no difference between your `Operation` interface and `DoubleBinaryOperator` except the name.

Answer (score 0):

(a, b) -> Math.pow(a, b)

The Math.pow returns a double type value. If lambda accepts int type cast it like

(a, b) -> (int) Math.pow(a, b) ;